# Django Channels Background Worker Instances

Tags: python, django, pusher, channel

I am working on a ***Django Channels-2 project***, where ***channel layer*** is used to offload information from browsers to a consumer who analyses it and send the results back to the Browsers via ***groups*** mechanism.

The data comes from ***pusher*** via a ***pusher-client***, and is therefore the same for many client browsers. My first took was to set-up the following infrastructure:

***layout 1:***
(**browser1:** Pusher-client, websocket; ... **browserN:** Pusher-client, websocket)
 <----> 
**WebsocketConsumer**(member of **group**; sends to **channel**, recieves from **group**)
 <----> 
**BackgroundWorker**(listens on **channel**; sends to **group**)

This layout works fine and it offloads the need to burden my server with the pusher connection, which is left to individual browsers. But this also means that I propagate multiple copies of the same event down to my Worker. I understand there are solutions to this problem, but they seemed a bit awkward to me. Also, this implies a lot of JavaScript-ing in the browsers. Even more so since only one websocket connection is permitted per browser tab and I need to traffic everything trough the same socket. Therefore I use the following set-up now:

***layout 2:***
(**browser1:** websocket; ... **browserN:** websocket)
 <----> 
**WebsocketConsumer**(member of **group**; sends to **channel**, recieves from **group**)
 <----> 
**BackgroundWorker**(***pusher-client***; listens on **channel**; sends to **group**)

In this layout, the browser notifies the consumers It wants results of the data, and if the background worker hasn't started yet it is spawned and starts pusher-client and on every event received analyzes the data and sends the result to group and hence back to browsers. This all works very nice and fine.

**THE QUESTION:**
Now, when I run

```
./manage.py runworker *channel-name*
```

The worker consumer isn't started until it is actually needed. And when the first message arrives to the channel it listens on, it is fired up and enters the event-loop of the pusher-client. Subsequent calls do not spawn additional workers, it would seems, and I have a flag if the pusher is already started, so I have only one connection to the pusher active.

**Q1:** Can I count on the background consumer to stay alive after it started or is there a timeout or something if there is no new message to be read in the channel que?

**Q2:** Is there a **better/more** reliable layout for my operations?

I had also an external websocket server version where pusher was active and results made available, but I didn't see how to elegantly integrate it into the django channels project although it worker perfectly fine. Is this nonetheless a better approach and utilizing unix-sockets?

**Thank you very much for your input!**

***[EDIT 1]***

I have found in the ***Channels-1.x*** series docs an entry in the FAQ section, that it is possible to communicate with the Django channels app also externally via the ***channel layer*** directly. So this is the approach I'm testing right now and it works beautifully. So I am currently doing it this way. Since both ***Q1*** and ***Q2*** are still valid and of interest to me, I will keep the question alive.

A quick overview of how it is being done at the moment for interested is being shown in the remainder of the edit:

***External.py***

```
from <proj-name>.asgi import channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import pysher
...
# External program logic #
...
# Channel layer communication -> send_group #
async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        <group>,
        {
            'type': "<type>",
            'data': <dict>,
        }
    )
```

***in asgi.py file of the Django Channels Project***

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<proj-name>.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()

# || the important part for us || #
# vv                           vv #
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

I'm running Django Channels 2.x series, which differs slightly from 1.x series. This setup eliminates the need for the background worker entirely, decouples pusher and django and makes things a bit easier at the moment.

Comment: Workers run all the time. They are not stopped or started. They just wait for work to be done. There is no timeout. There is no reason why you can't just do work on the Channel's consumer itself. Workers really only make sense if you want to continue to do something after the user disconnects.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. While experimenting I noticed that by overriding the `__init__()` method and simply doing `print(time.now())` and then `super()__init__(scope)` I can monitor the state of the worker and it turned out, that they are started (initialized) when first addressed via _channel_layer_. If they stay alive (`while True` loop - for instance) new messages via channels_layer did not start a new one. If they would  finish a new one would be started.
This problem has been solved via an external script communicating via channel_layers directly, but thank you for your input anyway.

Comment: I understand that my first use of the _background-worker_ mechanism wasn't exactly **canonical** so I completely understand the point @kagronick made. So thanks for your input. I managed my code differently now. I tried to _leverage-out_ non-django stuff into the workers but learned to do it better in the process.

Comment: Hi @LynxLike, I have a similar problem. So in your external.py solution, you manage running and keeping alive that script totally outside of channels, right? You don't need to setup it as a channels worker and use `manage.py runworker ..`. Am I understanding correctly? Thanks.

Comment: How can you setup it outside of channels by the way, to ensure it is kept alive and sharing resources with channels in a nice way?

Comment: @pembeci key is to import the channel layer of your channels app. If you make the file in the same directory as the project, then it is simply `from project.asgi import channel_layer`

Comment: @pembeci later in the script I call `async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send` to send to the group. I run this script seperatly as a background daemon. Hope that still helps.

Comment: @LynxLike, yes it helps. I got something working. Thanks a lot.